# Reverse engineer display string of ISymbol

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I am using [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PublicApiAnalyzers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PublicApiAnalyzers/) to get the text representation of public apis of my app. The text for a public api, for example the default constructor of a class A, is
`A.A() -> void`

The source code of the analyzer uses this method [ApiName GetPublicApiName(ISymbol symbol)](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/5102a0d89ef178b0ca741634ee006597bf5df2ed/src/PublicApiAnalyzers/Core/Analyzers/DeclarePublicApiAnalyzer.Impl.cs#L565) to produce the text representation of the api. Internally, this method uses the [ISymbol.ToDisplayString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.isymbol.todisplaystring?view=roslyn-dotnet) to construct the text representation.

Given a text representation, I would like to create a ISymbol instance from that.
But i cant find an api to do that, something like `ISymbol Parse(string)` or `ISymbol CreateFromText(string)`
Does such an api exist within [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis?view=roslyn-dotnet)
and i just havent found it, or should i try a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API that can generate a symbol from a string in Roslyn. You can create syntax nodes, pass them to a compilation object, and get the symbols from that compilation but you cannot generate symbols without a textual or syntactic representation.

If your goal is to generate types without having any syntactic representation for them I would look into [cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil).

If you do want to generate a type with underlying syntax I would look at the roslyn quoter website [here](https://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/).